# how to access list items which contains a string value separated with space?

Tags: string, flutter, dart

for my flutter app i am taking input from a scanner and the result of scanner is stored in scanBarcode variable,now i want to split this scanBarcode value(Apple 20) to 'Apple' and '20'. for that i have added that scanBarcode value(Apple 20) to a list called as 'item' from that i want to access last element of that list that is 20. but when i print that value i am getting whole string

[image]

this test variable i have printed in Text widget of my material app but i'm getting whole string ,i have tried with the help of 'test=item[item.length-1]' then also getting same entire string

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code. Post your actual code, so it can be copied, pasted, indexed by search engines and read by screenreaders for people having problems with the standard resolution screens.

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow, but i will consider your suggestion when asking questions in future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the part where you tell your program that you want to split the string at spaces:

```
final parts = scanBarcode.split(' ');

print(parts.last);
```

A list is just a list. If you add "Apple 20" to a list, it's a list with one element, "Apple 20".